# System.getProperty("user.dir") returns Eclipse base dir. path

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have created J2ee Dynamic web project and written code

```
<body><h1><%=System.getProperty("user.dir") %></h1></body>
```

but it's returning my eclipse Base dir path i.e "F:\Eclipse_Mars".
how I can resolve this or how to change it to the normal path.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "normal path".  Why don't you rephrase the question as:  "How can I get the path of XXXXX ?"  (and describe what you're trying to do in more detail, maybe with examples).

Comment: it's should return my project path like C:\Default_Workspace\Test

Comment: Why do you want the path of the project on your machine? What are you going to do with it?

Comment: The system property `user.dir` points to the base directory of your operating system user. Why do you expect it to return your project path? (btw I don't know why it points to the eclipse base dir - maybe you changed the property manually?)